# OAuth2 scope clarification needed

Tags: single-sign-on, identityserver3, oauth-2.0

I'm using IdentityServer3 but I'm not sure whether its a problem there or with OAuth2 generally or just my understanding of it.

```
tl:dr

How do I allow my user to have different claims in each app using single-sign-on?
```

Here's a scenario:

I want to arrange single-sign-on across a suite of apps so I have an identity server (lets call it IdSvr) and a couple of client apps (lets call them AppA and AppB).

AppA needs to know the user's profile info, email info and some AppA specific data. AppB needs to know the user's profile info, email info and some AppB specific data. To support this I set up scopes in IdSvr detailing the app-specific claims: scope "ScopeA" covers claims "A01", "A02", etc., and scope "ScopeB" covers claims "B52", "B53", etc.

Now when AppA needs to authenticate my user it makes a request to IdSvr asking for "openid profile email ScopeA" and gets back a token which gets the required claims, including "A01", "A02", etc.

When my user goes to AppB it finds he's authenticated so just gets the claims already obtained. There's no "B01", "B02", etc., because when AppA started the authentication it didn't ask for ScopeB.

In this case in order to get ScopeB claims I need to sign the user out and request a fresh authentication including ScopeB.

If my user goes back to AppA his ScopeA claims have been lost, even though he's still authenticated.

I expected the scope feature to let me keep claims apart, so that AppB specific claims don't interfere with AppA usage, and vice versa. I also expected that AppB would be able to make its own request, asking for ScopeB if the existing authentication didn't include it.

Have I misunderstood? Am I supposed to have the initial authentication get a token that gives access to all the user's claims, and make each consumer app responsible for filtering out stuff it doesn't need or shouldn't be privy to? What would be the point of scope then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The identity server stores a cookie so that on future requests you are already authenticated. Instead of a login screen you go straight to consent screen (if consent is required), then based on the scope/client it produces your claims and token. You do not need to logout to get a new token for AppB.

When IdentityServer redirects back to the client is passes the token via query string. How you store that token is entirely up to you.

Some obvious choices for caching the token are cookies or local storage. However if both apps are on the same domain and you are using the same key for caching/retrieving token then you would be pulling back the token cached by AppA or when you get token for AppB it could overwrite the AppA token.

Comment: OK, so AppB wants a scope that's not in the stored cookie because AppA didn't ask for it, so I'd expect IdSvr to show the consent view for ScopeB and then add claims to the token. I'm confused because each app is defined as a known client with allowed scopes, which sort of implies that each app gets a different token, but in practice it seems there's only 1 token which has to be copied to all callers.

Comment: "if both apps are on the same domain" made me realize I'm working with AppA and AppB both as localhost on different ports, so of course they're using the same cookie. I deployed my test clients to different domains and now they get separate scoped claims just as I hoped.